# Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. com/mongodb/util/JSON

Tags: json, mongodb, hadoop, hive

I am trying to connect MongoDb with Hadoop. I have Hadoop-1.2.1 installed in my Ubuntu 14.04. I installed MongoDB-3.0.4 and also downloaded and added `mongo-hadoop-hive-1.3.0.jar`, `mongo-java-driver-2.13.2.jar` jars in hive session. I have downloaded `mongo-connector.sh` (found in this [site](http://www.rackspace.com/blog/mongodb-and-hadoop-connect-your-data/))and included it under Hadoop_Home/lib.

I have set input and output sources like this :

```html
hive> set MONGO_INPUT=mongodb://[user:password@]<MongoDB Instance IP>:27017/DBname.collectionName;
hive> set MONGO_OUTPUT=mongodb://[user:password@]<MongoDB Instance IP>:27017/DBname.collectionName;
hive> add JAR brickhouse-0.7.0.jar;
hive> create temporary function collect as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';
```

My collection in MongoDb is this :

```html
> db.shows.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("559eb22fa7999b1a5f50e4e6"), "title" : "Arrested Development", "airdate" : "November 2, 2003", "network" : "FOX" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("559eb238a7999b1a5f50e4e7"), "title" : "Stella", "airdate" : "June 28, 2005", "network" : "Comedy Central" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("559eb23ca7999b1a5f50e4e8"), "title" : "Modern Family", "airdate" : "September 23, 2009", "network" : "ABC" }
>
```

Now I am trying to create a Hive table

```html
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mongoTest(title STRING,network STRING)
    > STORED BY 'com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.MongoStorageHandler'
    > WITH SERDEPROPERTIES('mongo.columns.mapping'='{"title":"name",”airdate”:”date”,”network”:”name”}')
    > TBLPROPERTIES('mongo.uri'='${hiveconf:MONGO_INPUT}');
```

When I run this command, it says

```html
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. com/mongodb/util/JSON
```

Then I added `hive-json-serde.jar` and `hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` jars and tried to create the table again. But the error remains the same. How can I rectify this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually added these `mongo-hadoop-core-1.3.0.jar` , `mongo-hadoop-hive-1.3.0.jar` and `mongo-java-driver-2.13.2.jar` jars in Hadoop_Home/lib folder. Then I was able to get data from MongoDb to Hive without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

There are smart-quotes which the parser is seeing - ”

```
 ”airdate”:”date”,”network”:”name”
```

They should be

```
 "airdate":"date","network":"name"
```

Comment: I have changed the quotes, but the same error exists.

Comment: Does replacing `${hiveconf:MONGO_INPUT}` with a static uri resolve the issue?